# Solve the equation in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all integers $(a,b)$ satisfying $$a^3-5a+28=2^b(2^b+1).$$

The problem seems a bit hard to begin with, I tried to make classification but got stuck when going further.
I believe that $(4,3)$ is the only solution.
Please help.

Comment: If $$x^3 + cx = d,$$ then $$x = \sqrt [3] {\frac{d}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4} + \frac{c^3}{27}}} + \sqrt [3] {\frac d2 - \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4} + \frac{c^3}{27}}}.$$ Now substitute $x = a$, $c = -5$ and $d = 2^b(2^b + 1) - 28$, and then continue from there...

Comment: @user477343 It's not working.

Comment: Well, I went here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/ in search of a cubic formula. and given the values of $p$, $q$ and $r$, I was able to come up with the foregoing formula. I also found this on the YouTube series, **Imaginary Numbers are Real**, so I am certain this is the formula. If it is not working, then this is a hard problem, because I assumed this would be a nice approach ......  But what *exactly* do you mean by the fact that it isn't working? Did the approach at all help you in any way?

Comment: @user477343 The question is to find integer solutions, not real or complex solutions. The general cubic formula won't help you in this case, because it involves taking square and cubic roots.

Comment: @MarcPaul I know, so the radicands have to be cubed numbers and etc. I thought information like that would help.

Comment: @user477343 I mean this the approach you mentioned isn't feasible here, and it really doesn't contribute to the simplification of the problem anyway. Don't get stuck in it.

Comment: @J.Guldan hahah I wasn't getting stuck on it. It's just that the one thing I don't like about maths, is that there isn't an actual method to finding the right method, if you know what I mean...

Comment: @user477343 Of course, there's not always one, and that's one of the reasons why maths is so charming.

Comment: @J.Guldan yes. My favourite is with the quadratic formula. We have the typical way of solving for $x$, and then there is also another way, known as the Citardauq variation (I think). This made me like maths even more, especially polynomial functions, but this is unrelated to the topic. I will go now. Hope the problem is solved soon :)

Comment: It seems that all integral points on the elliptic curve
$$y^2 + y = x^3-5x+28$$ are given by
$$(x,y) = (-2,5) \qquad (4,8) \qquad (1984,88371)$$
The last one is also $2(-2,5) + (4,8)$. Hence we can safely conclude your equation
indeed has $(a,b) = (4,3)$ as the only solution.

Comment: @pisco Do you have a proof?

Comment: @J.Guldan  The elliptic curve in question has small rank (rank 2), hence its integral points can be computed in a reasonable amount of time. The Sage command `E = EllipticCurve([0,0,1,-5,28]);E.integral_points()` gives the output up to the $y\leftrightarrow -1-y$ symmetry. You can also try `E.integral_points(verbose=True)` if you want to know the details.